# Least permission set to be able to use (nodejs) kafkajs's AdminAPI.listTopics()

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

The popular NodeJS Kafka client, kafkajs, has a method on the admin client part of it to list all the topics in the broker.

https://kafka.js.org/docs/admin

However this method returns an empty array when the Kafka user doesn't have enough privileges to fetch this information which to my knowledge comes from some sort of the metadata.

My question is, what is the minimum amount of privileges (READ/DESCRIBE, on what resource? TOPIC/METADATA) to add to my current use to be able to use the AdminPI.listTopics() via kafkajs?

I just need the array of all the topics, nothing more than that.

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you did use read permissions on any entity?

Answer (score 0):

Reading of topic entities, at a minimum to get a list

Describe is for reading individual topic configs